# Make twitter widget same height as DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

i'm trying to make my twitter widget (which is in its own div) the same height as another div (called mainslider). I've tried some stuff with JavaScript and JQuery but i'm not too experience with this.
An extract of my code is below:

```
    <div class="mainslider" id="mainsliderid">
    (SLIDER CODE HERE THAT I REMOVED)
</div>
<script>
var twitterheight = $('mainsliderid').height();
</script>
<div class="maintwitter">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitter" data-widget-id="704258053198254080" height="twitterheight" width="100%">Tweets by @twitter</a>
    <script>
        !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Quick and dirty: `jQuery('#maintwitter').height(jQuery('#mainslider').height());` - BETTER is to get the heights of both of them, and set them both to the largest height.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the twitter timeline can't be set to occupy 100% of the height. The only way to do it seems to be to set the height in pixels inside '<a class="twitter-timerline" href=".....' part. I tried doing it by make a script that creates a variable of the slider's height and then puts 'px' behind that but this doesn't work either, code for that is shown below (as an image sorry) [LINK HERE](https://i.gyazo.com/0f3ac8bddd8d181ced3c6e8a1c5aea38.png)

Comment: "Doesn't work", or doesn't set the height to what you want?  The `a` element is one single small button.  Additionally it would be VERY useful to see the rendered HTML, as opposed to the script that's running inside the div.

Comment: [RENDERED HTML](https://i.gyazo.com/dc6074dd4d71851eedefca508265fad8.jpg)

The twitter widget is at its default height of 600px here.

Comment: Hi - no, I mean the HTML - not the way it looks.  Without the HTML, we don't know what markup is avialable to access / modify / size.

Comment: Ok, i put it in pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/wepKnN75

Comment: Dominic - this still doesn't show the rendered HTML from within the twitter section.  Additionally, it doesn't show the script I provided / offered being used in the code - how you used it may have an impact.  (Be sure it's wrapped in a document ready: `jQuery(function($) { ... code from above ... });`

Comment: Oh ok, here it is with your code: http://pastebin.com/ZwnbCyDn
I'm not sure what you mean by the rendered HTML in the twitter section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the problem myself, and it was really simple. 
Due to the nature of the slideshow i had, its height was set proportionally to its width. Because i am using proportions of the screen width to change both the twitter and slideshows width i could just use the unit 'VW' which is 1 % of the screen width and just had to multiply it by the correct value. Works fine now.